# More elegant modulo conversion between 24hr time and 12hr time?

Tags: math, modulo

Converting 24-hour time (like military time) to 12-hr (clock-face) time seems like a perfect place to use the modulo operator, but I can't figure out a purely mathematical way to map 0 to 12 (so have hours 1 through 12 instead of 0 through 11). The best I've been able to come up with are either (in Ruby)

```
modHour = militaryHour % 12
if modHour == 0
  clockHour = 12
else
  clockHour = modHour
end
```

or,

```
hours = [12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
clockHour = hours[ militaryHour % 12 ]
```

It seems like there must be some way to accomplish this shift mathematically, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
hour12 = 12 - ((- hour24) % 12)
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

(pardon my Python...)

```
>>> for hr in range (24):
...   print hr, (hr + 11) % 12 + 1
... 
0 12
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 1
14 2
15 3
16 4
17 5
18 6
19 7
20 8
21 9
22 10
23 11
```

Comment: "pardon my Python" - is that a programmer chat up line? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Eric Jablow did not yield the correct answer for me. I found that this inline function worked though.

```
int militaryTime = 14;
int civilianTime = ((24hr - 1) % 12) + 1;
```